# Proof that a set is countable

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling with an exercise that I'm not sure how I have to approach to prove correctly.

Let $A$ be a set of nonempty Intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb {R}$. Assume, that for all $I_1 \neq I_2 \in A$:

$$I_1 \cap I_2 = \emptyset.$$

Prove that $A$ is countable.

Comment: Well, each non-empty interval must contain a rational so...

Answer (score 3):

Hint : Use that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and countable.

Comment: So basically because $\mathbb {Q}$ is countable and $\mathbb {R}$ isn't? Or where am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, for each interval you can choose a rational. This defines an injective map between $A$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, since intervals are pairwise disjoint. Hence, $A$ is countable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is as well. The same argument will work for any family of disjoint open sets in a separable space.